# Fast Shannon Entropy Calculation

Tags: optimization, entropy

Is there a fast way to calculate shannon entropy of a buffer of 16-bit numbers without having the calculate the log2 of every frequency count? The log calculations are quite slow.

Comment: Fast approximate logs might be worth a look? https://code.google.com/p/fastapprox/

Comment: Or maybe vectorized logs? https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-84D9D164-743E-496D-A1E4-4FB6F7F89A06.htm

Comment: Given a maximum of 65535 symbols, that's 65535 logarithms to be calcualted in the worst case. On my 5 year old computer this takes... (runs test) ... 1.8 milliseconds. The problem being...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the answer is that there is no way to do it without calculating the log function, but if you pre-calculate the logs, it's not so bad.

My buffer is 4096 bytes in size, so there are between 1..2048 of each possible 2-byte value. So the logs of 1/2048 .. 2048/2048 need to be pre-calculated. Then the calculation of each log is just an array lookup.